# How to change the default font of math operators

Tags: math-mode, fonts

How to change the default font of math operators? The problem is that if I use the command `\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathrm{U}{eur}{b}{n}`, only new defined operators will be changed in terms of its font. For the operators like `\sin` or `\sup`, no changes will take place.

```
\documentclass[english]{report}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb}
\DeclareMathAlphabet\mathrm{U}{eur}{b}{n}

\begin{document}
$$\sin,\sup$$

\end{document}
```

Comment: Please post a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) demonstrating the issue. Right now, I'm a bit confused about what you are really trying to do. Computer Modern is the default font. You seem to be trying to produce bold operators but, if so, this is not a good way to do it...

Comment: Thanks for adding an example. What are you trying to do exactly? Note that this font is not intended to be used for `\mathrm`. It is a symbol font which uses a 'raw' encoding (`U`). Also, you should not define the normal version using the `b` series. But it is hard to say what you should do without knowing what you are trying to do. Does `\usepackage{amsfonts}` do what you want?

Comment: ...just like I said. I wonder if it is possible to change the default font of math operators. I remember `\mathrm` defines the font of math operators

Comment: Yes, you can change it. But what do you want to change it to? You cannot change it to a font which doesn't include the right characters. Also, `$$` ought not be used - it is obsolete. Use `\[...\]` instead. (In LaTeX.)

Comment: Sorry I don't know what right characters you are referring to. I presumed that only upright latin alphabets are required.

Comment: Normally, `\mathrm` uses a font in the `OT1` encoding. But, in any case, you'd use `\SetSymbolFont{operators}{normal}{OT1}{lmr}{m}{n}`, say, to set a non-default font for this. And then you'd set the bold variant separately. But, generally, you ought not do this in your document. Packages exist to do it for you. In this case, just look at `amsfonts` and choose the options you want.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The usual definition of `\sin` is

```
\mathop{\operator@font sin}\nolimits
```

while `\operator@font` means

```
\mathgroup\symoperators
```

You won't find a definition place for `\symoperators`, because this is a byproduct of a

```
\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}...
```

instruction. So what you need is a new symbol font rather than a math alphabet.

```
\documentclass{article}

\DeclareSymbolFont{euleroperators}{U}{eur}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{euleroperators}{bold}{U}{eur}{b}{n}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\operator@font}{\mathgroup\symeuleroperators}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
$\sin(\pi/2-\alpha)=\log 1+\cos\alpha$
\end{document}
```

[image]

This will also work when `amsmath` is loaded and `\operatorname` or `\DeclareMathOperator` are used.

If you also want to define a new `\matheul` command, add

```
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\matheul}{euleroperators}
```

to the commands above. Note that `\mathrm` will continue to act as before.

Comment: What is the role of the line `\SetSymbolFont{euleroperators}{bold}{U}{eur}{b}{n}`? When I comment it, the output stays the same.

Comment: @Maggyero That's to make the change compatible with `\boldmath`.

Comment: Alright, but then why `\boldmath{\sin x}` has no effect (with or without `\SetSymbolFont{euleroperators}{bold}{U}{eur}{b}{n}`)?

Comment: @Maggyero `\boldmath` must be issued *outside* of math mode: `{\boldmath$\sin x$}` will do.

Comment: Thanks! And if I use the `unicode-math` package the operator names vanish, what should I change?

Comment: @Maggyero That's a completely different matter.

Comment: … that we can discuss [here](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/246304/changing-the-operator-font-with-unicode-math-loaded).

Comment: @Maggyero that discussion is just for change math operator font to sans serif style ...

Comment: @egreg Hi, I'm trying to get this to work with Adobe Garamond Pro (OpenType), which I load using fontspec. I've tried substituting "Adobe Garamond Pro" in place of "eur" and "OT1" in place of "U" in the code you provided, but so far it has not worked.

Comment: @Rations That's a new question, please ask it with a MWE

Comment: @egreg I've asked a new question here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/341007/80142

Answer (score 1):

In `fontspec`, you can download [the Neo Euler OpenType font](https://github.com/khaledhosny/euler-otf) and change the `\mathrm` font with

```
\setmathrm{Neo Euler}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
```

Unless something else in your preamble breaks it, this should change your operator font as well.  In `unicode-math`, you can set the operator font to something different than `\mathrm` with:

```
\setmathfontface\matheur{Neo Euler}[Scale=MatchLowercase]
\setoperatorfont\matheur
```

The excellent answer by @egreg already tells you how to do it with NFSS.