# Change font of math operators to fontspec font

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I'm trying to change the font of math operators (`\sin`, `\limsup`, etc.) to Adobe Garamond Pro, which I'm loading via `fontspec` for use with LuaTeX. I've tried modifying [this code](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/219417/80142) by egreg as follows:

```
\documentclass[letter]{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Adobe Garamond Pro}

% egreg code
\DeclareSymbolFont{garamondOperators}{OT1}{"Adobe Garamond Pro"}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{garamondOperators}{bold}{OT1}{"Adobe Garamond Pro"}{b}{n}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand{\operator@font}{\mathgroup\symgaramondOperators}
\makeatother

% Test code
\begin{document}
$\sup$

sup
\end{document}
```

The math operators display in Computer Modern even when I enclose the font name with quotation marks. Do I need to import Adobe Garamond Pro and assign it its own name within the preamble in order for it to be recognizable by `\DeclareSymbolFont`?

**EDIT:** It turns out that the problem was caused by my use of `lmodern` in conjunction with `fontspec`. Without `lmodern`, everything works flawlessly.

Comment: Please provide an actual compilable file. This one should be pretty short, but should still start at `\documentclass` and end at `\end{document}`.

Comment: @jon I've updated the example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need *no* special code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Futura} % a very distinctive one

\begin{document}

Math: $\sup$

Text: sup

\end{document}
```

I changed the font because I don't have Adobe Garamond Pro, but it's the same.

[image]

Comment: You're right. It turns out that my problem was caused by the lmodern package, which I had loaded at the top of the preamble. Do you know why this might be?

Comment: @Rations The `lmodern` package should not be loaded along with `fontspec`.