# Change font for 'operatorname'

Tags: math-mode, math-fonts

I started using `\mathsf{}` for things that one would normally use `\operatorname{}` for, since it's better distinguishable from non-math text. However, I've read that `\operatorname{}` has better spacing.

Is there a way to change the font used by `\operatorname` so I can continue using that, but with the different font?

Comment: Provide a `MWE`, there are many ways to achieve the request, below `Davislor` suggested method will works in `XeLaTeX` and `LuaLaTeX`

Comment: Do you want to do it for your own operators only or also for the standard ones?

Comment: @egreg actually I only want to change my own ones, but I have figured out by now that I can simply do e.g. `\operatorname{\sf lim}`

Comment: @user313032 Note that `\sf` has been deprecated since 1993. `\mathsf{lim}` would do.

Comment: Ahh yes `\operatorname{\mathsf{lim}}` works as well! Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

In `unicode-math`, you can use the command

```
\setoperatorfont\mathsf
```

Otherwise, you can use code [like egreg’s here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/219427/61644) to set the `\operator@font` to `\sfdefault`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{sansops}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{sansops}{bold}{OT1}{\sfdefault}{b}{n}

\makeatletter
\renewcommand\operator@font{\mathgroup\symsansops}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\[ f(t) = a \sin (-t) + b \cos(-t) + c \sinh(t) + d \cosh (t) + k \exp (t) \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Computer Modern sample]

For most documents, `OT1` encoding will work.  If you need accented Latin letters, but not uppercase Greek, you can change the legacy encoding from `OT1` to `T1`.  If you need lowercase Greek, you will need to find a sans-serif font that comes in the `OML` encoding.

Answer (score 7):

If you use pdfLaTeX and one of the "standard" LaTeX document classes -- `article`, `report`, and `book` -- to compile your document, you could run

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\operator@font{\sf}
\makeatother
```

in order to use the default sans-serif font for operator names.

A full MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
  \makeatletter
  \renewcommand\operator@font{\sf}
  \makeatother
\begin{document}
$\sin \cos \det \ln \exp$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Why `\sf` and not `\sffamily`?

Comment: @daleif -  Using `\sffamily` generates a "LaTeX Error: Command \sffamily invalid in math mode" error message.

Comment: That's interesting, one would assume `\sf` should not be used since the 90s, seems that did not follow along

Comment: @daleif there isn't an interface to do this so the "2e way" would be to define a math command to do essentially what `\sf` does in math mode, but if you are using a class where `\sf` is defined, just using `\sf` is easier.

Answer (score 1):

If your aim is to set text and mathematical context a part from each other, you may consider a distinct and dedicated math font for the later.  Why not [eulervm](https://ctan.org/pkg/eulervm) in conjunction to [mathptmx](https://ctan.org/pkg/mathptmx)

[image]

with the MWE of

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx, eulervm}

\begin{document}
The standard deviation $\sigma_{n-1}$ of the sample was computed as

\begin{equation}
\sigma_{n - 1} = \sqrt{ \frac{1}{n - 1} \sum^n_{i = 1} (x_i - \bar{x})^2}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

The other answers are great, but for my purposes the easiest and most flexible solution was to simply combine `\operatorname{}` and `\mathsf{}`, and write e.g.

```
\newcommand{\sflim}{\operatorname{\mathsf{lim}}}.
```

That has the advantage that I can use "operator names" with different font styles in the same document.